# PHP File Formatting issue: How do I fix an inconsistency in the writing output?

Tags: php

In a .txt file I have listed websites I wish to block in macs terminal. I call it ‘block_list.txt’.

```
rapradar.com
hiphopdx.com
thisis50.com
allhiphop.com
```

I have written a piece of code that opens the ‘block_list.txt’ file reading each line and puts each website into a format that I find works most effectively for my computers command line in blocking websites. I call it format_list.txt.

```
<?php 

$final_block_list = fopen('format_list.txt', 'rb+');
$handle = fopen('block_list.txt','rb+');


//$line =  fgets($handle);

foreach(file('block_list.txt') as $line) {
//fwrite($final_block_list, 

fwrite($final_block_list, 
"0.0.0.0 $line" . 
"0.0.0.0 www.$line"  . 
"0.0.0.0 http://$line"  .
"127.0.0.1 $line" . 
"127.0.0.1 www.$line" .  
"127.0.0.1 http://$line ".  
    "\n") ;

}
```

The issue I am having is that the last line does not format like the intended no matter how many different websites I add to the block list.

```
0.0.0.0 rapradar.com
0.0.0.0 www.rapradar.com
0.0.0.0 http://rapradar.com
127.0.0.1 rapradar.com
127.0.0.1 www.rapradar.com
127.0.0.1 http://rapradar.com

0.0.0.0 hiphopdx.com
0.0.0.0 www.hiphopdx.com
0.0.0.0 http://hiphopdx.com
127.0.0.1 hiphopdx.com
127.0.0.1 www.hiphopdx.com
127.0.0.1 http://hiphopdx.com

0.0.0.0 thisis50.com
0.0.0.0 www.thisis50.com
0.0.0.0 http://thisis50.com
127.0.0.1 thisis50.com
127.0.0.1 www.thisis50.com
127.0.0.1 http://thisis50.com

0.0.0.0 allhiphop.com0.0.0.0 www.allhiphop.com0.0.0.0 http://allhiphop.com127.0.0.1 allhiphop.com127.0.0.1 www.allhiphop.com127.0.0.1 http://allhiphop.com
```

How do I fix the last line of output ‘allhiphop.com’ so it is formatted like rest of first three websites were

Comment: Why don't you use a line feed between the entries? The current code works perfectly....

Comment: The only line break in your fwrite is at the very end...

Comment: The `http://` variants shouldn’t be in there to begin with. (What this does, is resolve host names to the local loopback interface, circumventing the “real” DNS. URLs are not host names.) And specifying two different IP addresses for the same host name is also nonsense.

Comment: I was hesitant to post this question on SO. I obviously do not wan't to have a question marked negatively. If anyone can tell me what is wrong with this post please let me know so I can ask more appropriate questions on SO. I did not know who else to turn to as a resource for finding a  solution in this case.

Comment: Also, a big thank you to everyone who answered.

Comment: @CBroe While you may be  right about the http:// variants, you do not own my machine. You do not know what works best for my computer. I assure you will find others online who need to do the same thing online with a simple google search.

Comment: If that should be a block list, it should be protocol-agnostic and thus not contain any protocols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial part is that you forgot to add line feeds between the entries. Just concatenating a string does not add them anywhere. This should work:

```
fwrite($final_block_list, 
"0.0.0.0 $line" . PHP_EOL .
"0.0.0.0 www.$line" . PHP_EOL .
"0.0.0.0 http://$line" . PHP_EOL .
"127.0.0.1 $line" . PHP_EOL .
"127.0.0.1 www.$line" .  PHP_EOL .
"127.0.0.1 http://$line ". PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL) ;
```

Comment: Since PHP allows multiline strings, you could also just leave the `" . PHP_EOL .` off every line.

Comment: This is a successful solution to the question. OP Needs to mark this as an answer